# Is there any good java tutorials for beginner/intermediate coders

Tags: java

does anybody have any beginners java tutorials that they've found useful? I would love to have a few for future reference.

Comment: _Thinking in Java_ by Bruce Eckel.  Some older versions are available on-line

Comment: I would start with Oracle's Java tutorials and google `{topic which interestes you} java tutorials`

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following Links it will may help you

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/
- http://www.mkyong.com/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

*see the related video about your query*...

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezwJKkf5q0I

Hope it will help...

Answer (score 1):

Check out thenewboston on youtube.  He's pretty easy to understand and won't bore you to death like some of the Lynda teachers

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28

Answer (score 0):

check [java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) tag info. It has lots of information. And if you find any other useful information do't forget to add that in java info.

Answer (score 0):

[Programming, motherfucker](http://programming-motherfucker.com/) has links for Java and many other languages. I go there first whenever I need to learn a language or someone asks for a reference. Picking up a Java edition of any Data Structures & Algorithms textbook can be quite nice too.

edit 1:

[Think Java, How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://greenteapress.com/thinkapjava/). I've read some other "Think X, How to Think Like a Computer Scientist" and have always been satisfied with them and keep a few (OCaml & Haskell & I think Prolog) as references.

Comment: @simmant I've never found another site that gave such good quality, centralized links to so many languages.